# SnakeYaml error: No writable property on class

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I've made a stupid mistake? I am new to yaml. Don't know why but my System does not see my variable called 'name'.

[Full error](https://hastebin.com/gadoqeputi.pas)

Error:

```
cannot create property=name for JavaBean=x.ModuleDescription@7ce6a65d
```

My class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ModuleDescription {

    private String name;
    private String main;

    private String version = "unknown";
    private String author = "unknown";

    @Setter
    private File file = null;
}
```

I can see this field but my system does not. Hope that anyone got an idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Well you declare the field `name` to be **`private`** which prohibits anyone else from accessing the field. By default, SnakeYAML only loads public fields and *properties*, i.e. values with public getters and setters.

So a simple fix would be to add a public getter and setter for `name` to the class:

```
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(final String value) {
    name = value;
}
```

For loading, you need the setter; for dumping, you need the getter. Alternatively, you can declare the field **`public`**.

If you *really really* want to keep the field private and *not* add any public getters / setters, this could also work (untested):

```
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
yaml.setBeanAccess(BeanAccess.FIELD);
ModuleDescription desc = yaml.loadAs(/* YAML source here */,
                                     ModuleDescription.class);
```

Comment: But I still got a public get and set for each field when i use @Data? Don't I ?

Comment: I have no idea what `@Data` is and you did not reference a library that contains it in the tags of your question, so I ignored it (*always* add relevant tags so that people know your complete software stack!). Anyway, SnakeYAML is not aware of what `@Data` does. To make that work with SnakeYAML, support would probably need to be added to SnakeYAML.